# Get and order biggest tuples from list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, flatmap

I'm trying to order my list and get the biggest 5 tuples in my list which will then be printed out, heres the code that i have been working with:

```
import scala.io.Codec.string2codec
import scala.io.Source
import scala.reflect.io.File
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SimpleWordCount {
def main(args: Array[String]) {

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Word Count")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val test = scala.io.Source.fromFile("/home/cloudera/Books/book1.txt").getLines


val wordCount =
test
.flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))
.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int]) {
  (count, word) =>
   count + (word -> (count.getOrElse(word, 0) + 1))
}



val formatteWordCount =
filtered
.map(tuple => s"${tuple._1} -> ${tuple._2}")
.mkString("\n", "\n", "\n")
```

when trying to launch the code the following lines gives the error:
diverging implicit expansion for type scala.math.Ordering[B]
starting with method Tuple9 in object Ordering

```
.sortBy(x => (x._2))
```

I also tried using  .stableSort(k, (x, y) => x._2 < y.*2) which gave the error value stableSort is not a member of String
and .maxBy(*._2) which gave the error diverging implicit expansion for type Ordering[B]
starting with method Tuple9 in object Ordering

```
 println(s"Final Word Count: $formatteWordCount")
```

}

Comment: Where are you calling the `sortBy`? what is the type of the collection on which you're calling it?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez (string, Int)

Comment: Are you sure?, bacause this works for me: `Map("hello" -> 1, "hadoop" -> 3, "world" -> 2).toList.sortBy(x => x._2)`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yeah that worked forgot the .toList thanks